# Disable PCI wifi to use USB wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, uninstall, realtek, pci

I own a hp laptop with pci realtek wifi adapter that's dosen't really catch any signal, so i got a TP Link TL-WN725N that works really well. My problem is that both wifi adapters are active and that it frequently switches to the internal one. I'd like to uninstall or disable the internal adapter to only use the USB adapter.

I know this has been posted several times, but I'm not able to solve the problem be reading other solutions as my knowledge of the command line is very limited.

That's the adapter I'd like to remove.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

In advance thank you very much for your patience and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8723be"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r rtl8723be
exit
```

You should be all set.